# How can i retrieve all products containing a specific attribute and attribute term using the woocommerce-rest-api

Tags: typescript, vue.js, rest, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I am trying to retrive all products with the "x-attribute" and "x-attribute-term". None of the ways i have found on stackoverflow and other sites have worked so far. I am using nodejs and this api: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-js-lib

I have tried

```
const response = await woocommerceApi.get("products", {
      attribute: "x-attribute-slug",
      attribute_term: "x-attribute-term-slug"
      per_page: 100,
    });
```

When i try this i just get all of the products in the woocommerce store.
I have also tried using the term "pa_x-attribute-slug" since i have seen people saying that woocommerce adds pa automatically, this didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Update: I found out how do it.

```
const response = await woocommerceApi.get("products?attribute=pa_[attributeslug]&attribute_term=[attribute term id]", {
      per_page: 100,
    });
```

without the []